# ASP.NET Resource resx String tooltip display help

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css, ajax, resources

I have a string, **Mini-move.Help**, stored in a resource file that I would like displayed whenever user clicks on the help image that is displayed.

**NOTE: the help image is displayed dynamically when you add the .HELP to your resource string.**

I want to style this display in such a way that when user clicks on the image button generated as a result of storing the resx file, a popup/tooltip like popup shows up instead.

```
Every Few Minutes - MM:
<br />Every Hour - H; <br />
Every Day - D;Su,Mo,Tu,We,Th,Fr,Sa;<br />
```

How do I accomplish this please?

thanks in advance

Comment: I can't quite understand what scenario you need to implement. Maybe you can provide some code instead of the content that you need to display?

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="[path]"  title="" onclick="this.setAttribute('title', '<%$ Resources:SiteResources,Mini-move.Help %>');" />
```

This will set title on image when click event occures